# How to Run scripts in vm from local machine browser

Tags: virtual-machine, hp-uft

I am able to execute the vbs files in VM (UFT Installed).Now I want to execute the vbs files in VM from my local machine (UFT Not installed).Can any one please help me how can i connect the QTP in VM from local machine and execute scripts.

I am using below code to connect to ALM/QTP in VM . Its working good because UFT is installed in VM. But in my case i want to host that code and get URL. So that every one from my team can use that scripts from there local machines (without installing UFT).

```
Dim qtApp 

Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")

If  qtApp.launched <> True then 
qtApp.Launch 
End If

qtApp.Visible = True


If Not qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then


qtplch.TDConnection.connect "QCLink","CERNATECH","EDUTRACKER","kiran.goud","kiran123",true


End If

qtApp.Open "[QualityCenter] Subject\filePath", False


qtApp.Test.Run


qtApp.TDConnection.Disconnect

'Close QTP
qtApp.quit

'Release Object
Set qtApp = Nothing
```

Comment: You could use something like `Jenkins` to manage and control your VMs and provide a web interface your colleagues can use to kick off scripts on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

VBS is always executed locally --> You need to keep this script on the machine where UFT is installed and provide a different way of triggering it remotely....

OR and this is a Big OR with some COM remoting use such a way:

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application", "NameOfTheMachineWithUFT_Installed")
```

The only difference is when you create the Automation Object, you tell the system that it should be created on an other machine and not locally.

However this is a High Security Risk and in most Enterprise Networks forbidden.
I would propose a simple wrapper around your script, eposed by a URL or as already suggested, Jenkins